# Why can my autorole bot work in my server but not others?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

So I am making an autorole bot for a friend. I sent the link which includes admin rights but when I tested to see if it would work in his server it did not and I got this error message below. I tested on my server to make sure it wasnt a problem with the code . The bot has admin rights so I do not understand why Missing Permissions would occur. Thanks in advance.

```py
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 20, in on_member_join
    await member.add_roles(rank)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 676, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 241, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

MY CODE:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import os
import keep_alive

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".", intents=intents)
role = "Ｍｅｍｂｅｒ"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot is online")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  rank = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name = role)
  await member.add_roles(rank)
  print(f'{member} was given {rank}')

keep_alive.keep_alive()

token = os.environ.get("TOKEN")

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py on\_member\_join not working even though the bot is in the server and online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64725909/discord-py-on-member-join-not-working-even-though-the-bot-is-in-the-server-and-o)

Comment: No sorry, I already have intents in my code

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: @Dock I have now added the code

Answer (score 1):

Here are few things that are giving PermissionError:

1. Bot can not give its top role
2. Member role should be lower than bot's top role
3. Bot should have enough perms to add role

Most probably in your case its the 2nd one, Member role is upper position than bot's top role

Comment: @selfcertifyy since this is the correct answer, mark it as correct by pressing the checkmark next to it

Answer (score 0):

The bot has not the needed permissions to make this ...
The bot need to have the manage roles permissions and the roles that should be manages must be under the bot role